# Asp.net mvc and google api

Tags: api

I created an asp.net mvc application that utilizes Google's analytic's API. The application was working for a short period, it then stopped working. By stopped working it is unable to make a connection to google. This problem occurs at my work environment. I tried the application at home and it works fine. I think my organization is blocking the application connection. I created a console version of the web app and it works fine.

Do web apps and console app make different external server requests?

How do I diagnosis the problem so I can make a request to the help desk as to what ports they are blocking.

thanks,

Comment: Removed ASP.NET MVC tag, this has nothing to do with MVC

Answer (score 2):

thanks for the help guys. I managed to route the api calls through a proxy server. 
Application worked fine after that. Here is a link to using a proxy with the api.

http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/proxy_setup.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), is a HTTP proxy that maybe can five you the information that you need. Other option would be mabye using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), for scanning too, but I'm not sure about it cause I never used it.

You need to install the tools on the client that is making the requests to Google

I hope this helps

Comment: So, I used fiddler to analyse the traffic. For some reason when fiddler is running my application works. My organization locks down the internet, so we are allowed to use an http proxy to connect to sites that are normally blocked. Could this be the reason why fiddler some how routes the traffic and allows my application to work?

Comment: Yeah, that would be maybe what is happenning.. have you tried to reach the URL that Fiddler gives you in your browser to see what happens? When you are making the test, Fiddler list all the URLs that it is calling

Comment: Frequently it's not your org but Google that sees a lot of traffic thru one IP address (because of your orgs proxy/server), so Google quits responding without user interaction.